# FFMPEG how to synchronize 2 video streams before comparison

Tags: video, ffmpeg, libavcodec, libav, libavformat

I am trying to write a ffmpeg filter to do some comparison between two video streams, the video stream is come from capture card, but when I try to compare the frames one by one, I found the frames is slightly not synchronize.

for example:

This is the first input stream frames order:

```
a, b, c, d, e, f, g....
```

And This is second:

```
c, d, e, f, g....
```

when I comparing the frames in the filter, I found that it becomes 'a' vs 'c', 'b' vs 'd'..., it's not synchronize.

Does there exists any way to synchronize 2 video streams?

thanks in advance!